# Diffie-Hellman between a C# Server and a Python Client

Tags: python, c#, encryption, diffie-hellman

I'm developing a C#-Server which shall communicate with a Python-Client. I want to encrypt the messages with AES and for the key exchange I want to use Diffie-Hellman.

When I try my server to load the public key sent by the client I get an CryptographicException which tells me that the parameter is wrong.

Here is my C# Code:

```
using System.Security.Cryptography;

//...

ECDiffieHellmanCng dh = new ECDiffieHellmanCng();
dh.KeyDerivationFunction = ECDiffieHellmanKeyDerivationFunction.Hash;
dh.HashAlgorithm = CngAlgorithm.Sha256;
BigInteger integer = BigInteger.Parse(key);  // key (string) contains the public key sent by the client
// Here is the error:
CngKey foreignKey = CngKey.Import(integer.ToByteArray(), CngKeyBlobFormat.EccPublicBlob);
byte[] key = dh.DeriveKeyMaterial(foreignKey);
```

Python-Code:

```
import pyDH
d1 = pyDH.DiffieHellman()
pubkey = d1.gen_public_key()  // This is the huge prime number which gets sent to the server
```

You can find the Python library at
https://pypi.org/project/pyDH/

Thanks for answering!

Answer (score 2):

I think pyDH uses (RSA) DH, while the ECDiffieHellmannCng uses Elliptic curves, namely the NIST P-521 by default. Try a python package like tinyec instead and choose the same curve for both the client and the server.

Comment: Not RSA DH which isn't a thing but rather mod p DH. But you're correct, those two packages are using completely incompatible groups.